# Как уничтожить Label и Entry Tkinter Python?

Tags: python, tkinter

Создаю label, ставлю его через place и пытаюсь удалить его self.label.destroy(), но ничего не получается, с entry то же самое, pack_forget не работает тоже. Combobox получается удалить через destroy. Как нужно удалять элементы label и entry?

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

class HoverButton(Button):
    def __init__(self, master, **kw):
        Button.__init__(self, master = master, **kw)
        self.defaultBackground = '#2A2C2E'
        self['bd'] = 0
        self['activebackground'] = '#3C3E3F'
        self['font'] = ('Roboto', 13)
        self['cursor'] = "hand2"
        self['bg'] = '#2A2C2E'
        self.bind("<Enter>", self.on_enter)
        self.bind("<Leave>", self.on_leave)
    def on_enter(self, e):
        self['background'] = '#262829'

    def on_leave(self, e):
        self['background'] = self.defaultBackground

class HoverLabel(Label):
    def __init__(self, master, **kw):
        Label.__init__(self, master = master, **kw)
        self['bg'] = '#17191A'
        self['fg'] = 'white'
        self['font'] = ('Roboto', 12)

class mainWindow:
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = Tk()
        self.root.configure(bg='#17191A')
        self.root.geometry("1050x650+400+200")
        self.root.minsize(850, 360)
        self.root.resizable(width=True, height=True)

        self.settings = [HoverButton(self.root, text="Button", fg='white', command=lambda: self.Settings()), 0]
        self.settings[0].place(x=20, y=180, width=150, height=70)


    def Settings(self):
        if self.settings[1] == 0:
            self.label = HoverLabel(self.root, text = "Text").place(x=600, y=30)
            self.settings[1] = 1
        else:
            self.label.destroy()
            self.settings[1] = 0
    


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = mainWindow()
    app.root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Добавьте ваш код в вопрос. Чтобы понять, что не так, нужно видеть что конкретно вы делаете. У меня никаких проблем с удалением виджетов никогда не возникало.

Comment: @insolor Добавил

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В этой строке:

```
self.label = HoverLabel(self.root, text = "Text").place(x=600, y=30)
```

в `self.label` записывается результат вызова метода `place` (который всегда возвращает `None`), а не объект `HoverLabel`. Из-за этого потом при попытке вызвать `destroy` вылетает ошибка, что у `NoneType` нет метода `destroy` (программа не прерывается, но в терминале эту ошибку видно).

Чтобы работало правильно, нужно вызовы `place`, `pack`, `grid` делать отдельно:

```
self.label = HoverLabel(self.root, text = "Text")
self.label.place(x=600, y=30)
```

Answer (score -1):

На самом деле

```
    self.label.destroy()
```

работает только в customtkinter. Вижу ты тоже новичок, что на tkinter кодишь. В tkinter нужно использовать функции например

```
    self.label.forget_pack() 
    self.label.forget_place()
    self.label.forget_grid()
```

в зависимости какой метод размешения использовался. Удачи в программировании!
Поправочка:destroy работает тоже в tkinter но видимо у тебя он не работает так что можешь использовать что я написал. Удачи!

Comment: destroy вполне работает в обычном tkinter.

Comment: Ну у тебя (или кто ты там ты) может не работает, а я использую то что я написал

Comment: Я все поменял. Посмотри

Comment: У автора вопроса он не работает именно из-за совмещения упаковки и присваивания в переменную. Почитайте соседний (мой) ответ.