# Проблемы с TkInter. Не могу взять данные для переменных

Tags: python, sqlite, tkinter

появился проблема в реализации изменения таблицы SQL с помощью GUI TKinter.
При написании самого функционала проблем не было,всё работало, ведь всё вводилось через консоль.
Сейчас мне надо брать значения из из окон Entry, беру с помощью .get(), но выдает ошибку:
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get'

Ниже приведу пример моего кода на основе одной функции. Само собой объявление и расположение всех виджетов сделано.

```
nname = text1.get()
ngender = text2.get()
nage = text3.get()
nkind = text4.get()
nidfood = text5.get()
rowtoedit = text6.get()



with date:

    date.execute(""" 
        UPDATE Animal SET name=?,gender=?,age=?,kind=?,ID_Food=?
        WHERE ROWID =?""",
                 (nname,ngender,int(nage),nkind,int(nidfood),int(rowtoedit))
                 )
date.commit()
ntype = text7.get()
nFirm = text8.get()
nCost = int(text9.get())
nnamefood = text10.get()
rowtoedit1 = int(text11.get())
with date:



    date.execute(""" 
         UPDATE food SET Type=?,Firm=?,Cost=?,NameFood=?
         WHERE ROWID =?""",
                 (ntype, nFirm, nCost, nnamefood, rowtoedit1)
                 )
date.commit()
```

Comment: в ошибке ясно сказано, что nname (или что-то ещё) NoneType. Проверьте их инициализацию

Comment: и, если мне память не изменяет, параметры обязательны  -  text.get(1.0, END)

Comment: @splash58 всё это - локальные переменные в функции, но даже с их преждевеременно инициализирую, то код не будет работать, проверял
А насчет параметров - благодарю вас, не знал

Comment: да почему же не будет. как вы их инициализируете?

Comment: @splash58 Да как всегда и делал. name = '' /n ngender='' и тд

Comment: я про text1 и остальные. типа, `text1 = tk.Text()` - такое у вас есть?

Comment: @splash58 Да, само собой, только вместо Text использую Entry()

Comment: значит функция их не видит, раз в них None

Comment: Добавьте как вы инициализируете text1 и прочее. Если что-то типа `text1 = Entry().pack()` (или place или grid), то в переменную попадет не виджет, а результат вызова метода pack/place/grid, который всегда None. См. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1143721/1365

Comment: insolor, да, была проблема в самой инициализации, в точности как вы описали)
Благодарю!

Answer (score -1):

я вам посоветую перейти на customtkinter и помогу решить проблему.

```
    import tkinter as tk
    
    root = tk.Tk()
    list = []
    def submit():
        list.append(entryget.get())
    #Сейчас я инициализирую переменную которая берет значение виджета 
    tk.Entry. 
    entryget = tk.StringVar()
    #Если у вас циферный ввод используйте метод tk.IntVar()
    
    e = tk.Entry(root, textvariable=entryget)
    e.pack()

    b = tk.Button(root, text="Submit", command=submit)
    b.pack()
    
    root.mainloop()
```

Извините что описываю все на примере своего кода так как ваш непонятен и неполный. Тут суть в том что метод .get() нужно добавлять к переменным виджета а не к самому виджету. Надеюсь, ответ был полезным. Удачи в програмировании!